# MySQL rows lost but got .MYD file

Tags: mysql

I have the following problem. Apparently yesterday we had the bad luck of 1 of our main tables completely deleting all records and keeping just 1 out of 450 records.

At the moment i still have the .myd file, the .frm file and the .myi file as original with all the data inside the .myd file. I've tried a few things but just can't get the data to be shown on the actual database.

Is there any way to recover the data from the .myd file? Otherwise i'll need to actually make it manually. (I am bit of a beginner in terms of MySql)

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I have not tried it before, but check this https://www.arekibo.com/blog/restore-a-mysql-database-from-backed-up-program-files-(-frm-myd-myi)-no-sql-dump-required!/

Comment: Unfortunately, this question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO provides help in database admin related questions like this. (Restoring data from a backup would be the simplest thing to do, though.) When asking your question on the DBA site, pls list the things that you have actually tried, avoiding people suggesting the same method, thus wasting everyone's time.